# Include a Tab in Barcode's content in MS Word

Tags: ms-word, barcode, mailmerge

I am implementing a mail merge for a number of mails, and in these mails I am going to include a piece of barcode, whose contents includes customer ID and activity ID. I would like to put a TAB in between these 2 values, so that I can fill in 2 fields in my CRM form with one scan on the barcode.

Now I am stuck at putting in Tab as a control character in the barcode **field** (I emphasise this because I am using MERGEBARCODE / MERGEFIELD to generate barcode). Any ideas on possible solutions or alternatives?

Comment: I recommend you ask this in an end-user venue, such as Super User. Stack Overflow is for programming issues and while it can deal in field codes you're more likely to find someone familiar with this in the end-user venue.

Comment: To do that, you would have to use a barcode that is supported by Word *and* accepts tabs as inputs.